# Implementing a MUX schematic from boolean expression

Tags: boolean

We're learning about multiplexers right now in my class, and we have an assignment to implement the expression x+z'y using 3 or fewer MUXs.

I'm not asking you guys to do it for me. I really just need some direction. So far I have the truth table written out. Would it help to write different variations of the truth table? I'm also confused on feeding the output of one MUX into another.

Answer (score 0):

We may be in the same class.. 160 at UTK?

Anywho.. This helped me out a lot: http://class.ece.iastate.edu/arun/CprE281_F05/lectures/f05_week05.pdf

Specifically, slide 6. If you already have the truth table, you're half-way there! Our professor uses a different style of MUX schematic, but it isn't too hard to correlate. Let me know if you're still confused!